# Codable variable in Codable Class

Tags: swift, codable

Given this class:

```
class MyClass: Codable {
    var variable : Codable? = nil
}
```

I get error:

> Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
>
> Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

How can I have a generic variable that conforms to Codable as a property in a Codable class?

Comment: None of the answers have actually covered the reason for your error: it is because [Swift procotols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

Comment: I believe it has to do with Codable. [This code works](https://gist.github.com/hayek/b7bdd14e720e36ad5b38ba518d1adf73).
I think the reason is Codable itself, check out  Y.Bonafons answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be like this if i got your question correctly

```
class MyClass<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var variable : T? = nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you try to implement your decoder you will have something like:

```
class MyClass: Codable {
    var variable: Codable?
    enum MyClassKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case variable = "variable"
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: MyClassKeys.self)
        variable = try! container.decode(XXXX, forKey: .variable)
    }
}
```

But instead of XXXX, you should put a class type (for example `String.self`). What can you put here? Its not possible for the compiler to guess what you want. Instead of `Codable` type maybe you can put a class which conform to `Codable` protocol. So you can have something like this:

```
class MyClass: Codable {
    var variable: MyClass?
    enum MyClassKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case variable = "variable"
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: MyClassKeys.self)
        variable = try! container.decode(MyClass.self, forKey: .variable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me understand why I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

But as a workaround, you can create an `enum` conforming to Codable.

```
enum SubType: Codable {
    case foo
    case bar
}
```